# Why isn't my CORS fetch request sending cookies to the server?

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, fetch, cross-domain

I've got a fairly simple CORS request using fetch:

```
    fetch('https://foobar.com/auth', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
    })
```

express handles this server side; my code to protect one route via CORS looks like this:

```
app.get('/auth', cors({
    origin: [
        'http://localhost:8080',
        'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
    ],
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: true
}), (req, res) => {
    const { jwt } = req.cookies;
    console.log('JWT is: ', jwt);
    res.json({ jwt });
});
```

But, the response is always empty, it cannot retrieve the cookie from the request and send it back in the json response.

In the browser dev tools, I see this in the response headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

(I tried with localhost as well, but this didn't work, and someone suggested using the IP, I dunno).

If I hit the server directly, on the `/auth` route, I do get back JSON with the JWT token, so I know it is stored as a cookie that is passed back and forth each time, and can see it in the cookies of the browser dev tools.

```
{"jwt":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.kaRH97GyIjgfdbfhOO4zaMLrZKD7bRV23wpAvd4v-As"}
```

I see in the response headers this too:

```
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3As-DAIzZjWT4C3xxxxxuAUgE; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
```

Should I see the set-cookie for the JWT? I was assuming it would not need to re-set it, but I'm unclear if that indicates the server is not correctly setting it, and then retrieving it, and then sending it back to the CORS request.

My understanding is that to make this work, I just need to:

1. Setup cors on the server side to properly set the access-control-allow-origin header.
2. Send my request from the correct origin.
3. Specify in the request that I need to allow credentials to get the cookie (use `credentials:true` in my fetch call, which sets `access-control-allow-headers` in the request itself.

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem? And what do you mean by "the response is empty"? If you set the cookie as an http only cookie there is no way to get it using javascript. Even if it is not set as http only still cookies are not sent in the response of the api call.

Comment: The cookie is stored in browser associated to the remote domain, not the domain the page is on. Agree with other comment, not clear what problem really is

Comment: @voxtool I'm trying to make a request to the /auth route and get back a jwt token. Prior to this, I'm logging in at foobar.com, which after authentication creates a secure cookie in the browser. The user application is on another domain. If the /auth route returns nothing, they are directed to foobar.com to login, then redirected back to the application, then my app again requests /auth and I wanted that to give back the auth jwt token.

Comment: @charlietfl yes, the cookie is stored on foobar.com. My app runs on a different domain, hence the need for CORS. Is it not possible to make a get request over CORS to another domain and have cookies go with it that the server can use to generate a request

Comment: @xrd Ok, if I understand correctly you have a cookie and you see it in the application tab i devtools and you want the server to extract the jwt from the cookie and send it to you via json. If that is the case you can get the cookie in express this way: **const token = req.cookies['the name of  your cookie']**

Comment: @voxtool: My express code does that, right: `const { jwt } = req.cookies;`. If I use the route directly (hit that in the browser without fetch) it works and the JSON response is good. If I use fetch (even with the configuration), the cookies are not sent and my server cannot use them.

Comment: @voxtool: It says I can send cookies using fetch here: https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies. But, I don't see that in the request headers with CORS, though I do see the cookies sent when I am putting that into the location bar and making a regular request. I'm confused, why is fetch not sending the cookies with that configuration?

Comment: @charlietfl Ah, I see what you are saying. The cookie is indeed stored on 127.0.0.1:8080 NOT on foobar.com. I'm baffled this is the case, I guess this is because I redirect after login from foobar.com? But, I suppose I can now retrieve purely in JS by accessing the cookie in the domain on why my app runs (127.0.0.1:8080).

Comment: You can't access secure cookies with client side js

Comment: I deleted the cookies and went through my flow again, It is not there, so the original question remains. That must have been an old cookie set by another app using 127.0.0.1:8080. @charlietfl I don't think this is a "secure" cookie (not encrypted), it is served over HTTPS but that's different, right?

Comment: When I look at the cookie in the browser, it indicates "this cookie did not set Same-Site so it uses lax." I wonder if I need to set the cookie to permit access outside of the original domain when using fetch+cors?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that express was not creating the cookie correctly. It needs to be created with sameSite: 'none' as an option to have CORS requests use it.

```
const jwt = "abc123";
const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
const options = { secure: true, sameSite: 'none', httpOnly: true, maxAge: expiresIn };
res.cookie('jwt', jwt, options );
```